# Ruby on Rails application with Lucene

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lucene

I developed a brief desktop app with java using Lucene, now I want to port it into a web application that  I'm programming  with ruby on rails framework. Is there a good porting library (gem) that can I use like lucene in java for my purpose??? 
I have already used Ferret but many times the results are wrong compared with lucene version
Thanks a lot for your responses....

Comment: Use solr is an option?

Comment: Do you known alternative like ferret.... solr is a server, I would like to use a library....

Answer (score 0):

@enjoytech

ElasticSearch and Solr are good option for big application & customise searching response and Sphinx is also good for mid level application with less customisation.

Sphinx + MySQL works super